# "Ключница водку делала" — похвала или критика?

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов

В фильме "Иван Васильевич меняет профессию" царь Иоанн Грозный, выпив "Столичную", говорит: "Ключница водку делала?". Есть эта фраза и у Булгакова.
Хвалит царь водку или ругает?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте вспомним текст булгаковской пьесы:

Тимофеев. Вы водку пьете?

Иоанн. О горе мне!.. Анисовую.

Тимофеев. Нет анисовой у меня. Выпейте горного дубнячку, вы подкрепитесь и придете в себя. Я тоже. (Вынимает водку, закуску.) Пейте.

.............

Иоанн. Ключница водку делала?

Тимофеев. Ну, пускай будет ключница... долго объяснять...

http://www.lib.ru/BULGAKOW/ivan_vas.txt

Сдаётся мне, фраза эта — не хвала и не хула, а удивление от неожиданной крепости. Видимо, в анисовой водке-настойке градусов много меньше и она приятней на вкус, а "Горный дубняк" 20-30-х — на желудях, имбире, красном перце и пр., т.е. очень терпкая и крепкая водка, 40 градусов (за что большевиков осуждали, но водку закупали в больших количествах).
Вот и здесь та же ситуация: И.В. сразу понял, что это не элитный напиток, а что-то вроде самогона, который гнала ключница из прокисшего варенья. Возможно, он сделан, обойдя монополию, т.е. незаконный, но крепость его пришлась по душе, потому что дальше он к нему ещё не раз в одиночестве прикладывался, пока Тимофеев бегал в магазин.

Comment: Настоящая-то водка-то всегда была сорокаградусная. При чем тут большевики? Если совсем точно, в современных единицах уарский стандарт соответствовал 38.3 градуса. Разницу вряд ли можно ощутить на вкус. Вот и другой герой Булкаова, Филипп Филиппыч недвусмысленно на этот счет высказался. Скорее уж именно у ключницы водка могла быть 30 градусов.

Comment: Если не вдаваться в тонкости "градусности", очевидно что вкус водки был непривычный. Спасибо за цитату из Булгакова!

Comment: Нет, не всегда.До XIX века крепость водки "скакала" от 25 до 38 градусов. В 1894 году создается  комиссия во главе с Д.И. Менделеевым. Ученые доказывают, что можно без проблем округлить крепость водки до 40 градусов – это оптимально, чтобы почувствовать ее вкус. Если напиток крепче – он просто обжигает.
Все последующие водки имеют в своей основе сорокоградусный закон Менделеева. http://dist-tutor.info/mod/book/view.php?id=41595

Comment: http://mercuryalko.ru/culture/drinks/vodka

Comment: В "Горном Дубняке" точно было 40 градусов. Правда, Гайдай в своём фильме заменил его на "Столичную"(тоже 40 градусов), да и вообще перенёс действие из 20-х в 70-е, если Вы заметили. А у Булгакова акцент именно на крепости, а про ключницу - намёк на нелегальность, он же казнил тех, кто нарушал монополию.

Comment: @Людмила Участие Менделеева в появлении сорокоградусной водки - миф! https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Менделеев,_Дмитрий_Иванович#Легенда_об_изобретении_водки

Answer (score 3):

"Хвалит, ругает" - это вообще "не из той оперы".
В фильме, если присмотреться, Грозный говорит это с некоторым подозрением.
Конечно, во времена Грозного ни "ключниц", ни "водки" в помине не было. Здесь, видимо, аллюзия на времена скорее гоголевские, когда на водку была государственная монополия, но самогон гнали как и веком спустя - в булгаковской современности.

Comment: Может и не из той оперы - в интернете много страниц где по этому поводу ведутся жаркие споры. Замечание насчет подозрения интересное - видимо царю водка не понравилась.

Comment: Да пускай ведутся. Сейчас готовы спорить о чем угодно. Я свое мнение высказал. А подозрение - да, но так то ж только в фильме. Булгаков его (фильма) не видел.)))

Comment: Пересмотрел этот фрагмент - про подозрение трудно сказать. Похоже царь не ожидал такой крепкой водки, поэтому сморщился и почти прошептал эту фразу. Интересно, все-таки, что Булгаков имел здесь в виду.

Answer (score 0):

Ключница — должность прислуги, подразумевающая хранение ключей от всех замков в доме. Наиболее важная должность, на которую могли назначаться только ответственные и добросовестные люди из челяди. Часто им доверяли и прочие ответственные (и конфиденциальные) поручения. Например — изготовление настоек. Характеристика «Ключница водку делала» отражает признание превосходных качеств напитка, его достойной крепости.